# Limit framerate in Unity Editor for game window

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to limit my FPS to 30, as I really don't need more.
Naturally I've tried to set the Application.targetFramerate to 30, as well as QualitySettings.vSynCount to 0.
The FPS always stays close to 60. I've also tried to set vSyncCount to 2, which also doesn't work.

How can I limit the FPS in Editor game view? (Note: not scene view)

I am on Linux, Unity v 2017.1.1.

Comment: I was never able to get this to work in Start() or Awake(). I managed to get it to work by starting a coroutine that waits 1 second after Start() and then sets Application.targetFramerate. Note: vSyncCount has to be 0.

Comment: I tried that too, but that also doesn't work for me. Even setting targetFramerate in update doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm.. Weird thing to try, but looking at the forums some people were saying that the script wouldn't work if attached to a camera.. They had to attach it to an empty GO. Also, if you have any plugins in your project,  some of them could be causing your values to reset. I would do a debug.log of both values in Update just to check if they start out with what you want and then change.

Comment: Just now tried a separate GO and that didn't work either unfortunately. I logged both variables and they both display the correct values. Guess this is a bug I can't get around of.. Thanks for thinking along though

Comment: Dang, well.. Sorry this can't work for you :/ Please make sure to make a bug report with Unity so they can fix it!

Comment: I accidentally stumbled onto a fix. Calling Screen.setResolution(w,h,false); before setting vSyncCount and targetFramerate shows that works in Editor. Hurray :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If Screen.setResolution is called before, then targetFramerate and vSyncCount are adhered properly in Editor game view.

```
    Screen.SetResolution (1920, 1080, false);
    QualitySettings.vSyncCount = 0;
    Application.targetFrameRate = 30;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this stopped working as I updated to 2017.3.

Comment: Actually it still works, but targetFramerate is not very close to the actual framerate it seems. So set it lower than 30 for 30 fps for example. E: SetResolution doesn't seem to help anything, at least not anymore. Just lower the targetFramerate more, it seems FPS is being overshot from targetFPS.

Comment: Yes! tried this as of Jan 2021 and it is working for me on my Macbook in the editor.  This was driving me insane - my Macbook was overheating and constantly running at 300+ fps!  Now my game is currently running nice and quiet at around 40fps. Thanks.